# I am trying to calculate the standard deviation of sales demand.

Tags: probability

198 days total.

Here are the sales numbers for days with a sale(16 days):
24,20,10,10,10,2,6,10,12,10,12,12.24,1,13,12

182 days without no sales

what is the standard deviation? should the 182 zero's be included in the calculation?

Comment: Of course you should include the zeros.  Don't you want to distinguish between 182 zeros and 18200 zeros?

Comment: Yes - that is what I thought but when I calculated the safety stock, it didn't seem to give me enough inventory to cover the higher daily sales numbers

Comment: I hope you are not using normal distribution table for you calculation... The distribution you have is rather special.  If you want to know how many units are need to meet demand, say, 98 percent of the time, just work with the collected data directly, using percentiles.

Comment: could you elaborate a little on that, I am not sure what you mean.

Answer (score 1):

For your $n = 197$ days, I got a sample mean of $\bar X = ,834$ and
sample standard deviation $s = 3.297.$

For what it's worth, $A = \bar X + 2s = 7.43$ and 
$B =  \bar X + 3s = 10.73.$ The fraction of days on which
demand exceeded $A$ was 6%, and the fraction exceeding $B$
was 3.6%. So an inventory somewhere between 8 and 10 
seems to satisfy demand 95% of the time.

You don't really say what relevance $s$ has to your situation.
I have no idea whether these facts are relevant, how long
it takes to get stock when demand exceeds supply, or whether
keeping an inventory of 10 is financially feasible.

Answer (score 0):

I guess Bruce's answer took the 12.24 literally as 12.24 and not as a 12 and a 24, which is what I guess it's intended to.

Using R I got $\tilde X\approx0.9495, Var(X)\approx13.5, standard\ deviation\approx 3.6742$

And yes, you should include the $0s$ since they are giving information as well. You want to know how your values are dispersed, so you have to include every value. That's, of course, assuming that all the days are evaluated the same way by the random variable $X$. What I mean with that is, if the random variable $X$ gives the number of sells when the shop's opened, you don't have to take into account that you had $0$ sells when the shop was closed. Be very careful with your definitions.

Comment: I was using the standard deviation to calculate the safety stock and came up with a value of 17 which wouldn't cover the demand on the highest sale days - one week lead time with an average demand of 5 which would have left us short on 12% of the sale dates